# getting unknowing symbol Â before © symbol - HTML

Tags: html, css

```html
<p class="reportproblems">
  To report problems or comments with this site, please contact 
    <a href="mailto:abc@gmail.com">business@business.com</a>.
        <br>© Business LTD. All Rights Reserved.
 </p>
```

As above, I have

tag in my HTML code, but when I open the page in the web browser, I get an unknown symbol "Â", before the "©" symbol.

> Is there any way to fix the glitch ?

edit:
All the HTML content is coming from a third party server, hence, editing the content will not be possible. Management of everything using CSS, or CSS over rides, is necessary.

Comment: Make sure you're using UTF8 everywhere.

Comment: it's called encoding.

Comment: Have you set the charset appropiated in the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the following three methods

[**HTML Symbols**](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_symbols.asp)

```html
<p> &#169;</p>
<p> &#xA9;</p>
<p> &copy;</p>
```